# Dynamic initialization phase of static variables

Tags: c++

The standard specifically states that dynamic initialization of static duration variables (namespace scope and class static members) does not have to occur before main is executed:
 "It is implementation-defined whether or not the dynamic initialization (8.5, 9.4, 12.1, 12.6.1) of an object of namespace scope is done before the first statement of main." IS 3.6.2(3)
Is it not how dynamic initialization is [always?] implemented? What better/easier way to guarantee that the objects are initialized before use?

Comment: Where did you read that?  I'm not sure it's true.  You may be thinking of the "static initialization order fiasco" (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14), but that's nothing to do with `main()`.

Comment: See my edit: 3.6.2(3) of the IS

Comment: I don't know what the C++ standard says, but at least in C "the manner and timing" of static initialization is unspecified behavior. The only requirement is that they are set before the program in started. In a hosted environment, this means they must be initialized before main() is called.

Comment: C doesn't have a dynamic initialization phase for static duration variables and constants. The initializer has to be a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the intention here is to allow dynamic load libraries.

Static variables defined in the libraries are not guaranteed to be initialized before main, but must happen before anything in the specific library is used.

Comment: @John Actually it doesn't make much sense really. Dynamically linked libraries are loaded and initialized before execution starts (so before `main`). Unless library is loaded explicitly - like with `LoadLibrary` (winapi) or `dlopen` (POSIX) - this however is out of the realm of C++ standard (as evident from the fact that explicitly loaded libraries are not subject to ODR, etc. - because they do not really become part of globally available name space within a process - their symbols must be explicitly queried too). See my answer latest amendments.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is in the next sentence (in 3.6.2 of ISO/IEC 14882-2003) after the one you've quoted.

> It is implementation-defined whether
> or not the dynamic initialization
> (8.5, 9.4, 12.1, 12.6.1) of an object
> of namespace scope is done before the
> first statement of main. **If the
> initialization is deferred to some
> point in time after the first
> statement of main, it shall occur
> before the first use of any function
> or object defined in the same
> translation unit as the object to be
> initialized.**

Obviously to make sure that some variable `X` is initialized you just have to use in function `main` (directly or indirectly) any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable `X` (e.g. if you directly or indirectly use `X` in function `main` then you may be sure it is already initialized).

**EDIT:**

If in addition to the assurance that the variable you use is already initialized (it always is - as guaranteed by the standard text quoted above) you also want to know why standard contains the provision that initialization may be delayed after `main` execution start.

I mean if the question is also: *Why not just demand that all initialization is performed before `main` starts?*

Well it is definitely not about *dynamically linked* libraries - no problem to initialize all their objects before starting `main`. Also it is not about *dynamically loaded* libraries (`LoadLibrary`/`dlopen`) - they are not within a realm of C++ standard obviously (they are not subject to One Definition Rule for example and in general they may even be not C++).

In theory this provision allows lazy initialization to avoid unnecessary runtime overhead - e.g. unless you actually use some function or object from a specific translation unit (C++ source file) you don't have to do its runtime initialization. But it is unlikely that any implementation actually do lazy initialization in runtime - multi-threading synchronization is challenging for this kind of initialization and is itself a runtime overhead.

**BUT** what every single implementation actually do is linking only those modules (translation units) that are actually used. So even if you link with some static library that contain some dynamically initialized object (maybe with side effect - like file creation or user interaction) but don't use anything from the same translation unit - implementation is not obliged to run initialization of this object at all. So this provision allows avoiding inclusion of any unused translation units in final executable - even if they are formally part of the program.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer, but it might be interesting for comparison's sake to go over how a similar language (Ada) handles this same situation.

In Ada packages (the rough equivalent to namespaces) can have data with initializations which effectively have the same lifetime as the program, much like Cish statics (for simplicity we will ignore generic packages, which like templates may be created in lower scopes). The process of doing these initializations is called "elaboration".

Ada guarantees that all packages will be elaborated at the start of the main routine. However, it is quite possible to create "elaboration" code that will not work if another package has not yet been elaborated yet. In general, the compiler gets to pick the elaboration order. So writing code that will not work unless the compiler happens to pick the order you need is considered a "Bounded Error".

Obviously this isn't ideal, as it is often desirable to use non-builtin data types in other packages, and sometimes this will include some with initializations that will need to be elaborated. So Ada provides some `pragma`s to allow you to ask the compiler to elaborate some or all of your dependencies before the current package.

It isn't perfect. It is quite possible to write code for which there really is no valid elaboration order. If you do this (or don't get the pragma's right and the compiler can't figure it out either), you get a `Program_Error` exception raised during elaboration. Some debuggers have trouble stepping through elaboration code, so these errors can be a major PITA to track down. Nonetheless, I really miss this facility in C++. It is the difference between being able to use complex objects in "static" declarations if you are careful, and having to avoid them altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic initialization of static duration variables (namespace scope and class static members) **ALWAYS** occurs before main is executed.
The order in which these static duration variables get initialized is not defined.

Comment: Well, some parts of the order are defined.  In particular, statics within one particular translation unit are initialized in declaration order.

Comment: Notice my edit of my question. 3.6.2(3) says that it doesn't have to occur before main is executed.

Comment: "The dynamic initialization of static duration variables (namespace scope and class static members) ALWAYS occurs before main is executed." In most implementations. But **not** guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @Oli: "statics within one particular translation unit are initialized in declaration order" In order of **definition** (there may be more than one declaration).