# C++ compilers implementing dynamic initialization after main

Tags: c++

The C++ standard section 3.6.2 paragraph 3 states that it is implementation-defined whether dynamic initialization of non-local objects occurs after the first statement of main().

Does anyone know what the rationale for this is, and which compilers postpone non-local object initialization this way?  I am most familiar with g++, which performs these initializations before main() has been entered.

This question is related: [Dynamic initialization phase of static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372032/dynamic-initialization-phase-of-static-variables)
But I'm specifically asking what compilers are known to behave this way.

It may be that the only rationale for this paragraph is to support dynamic libraries loaded at runtime, but I do not think that the standard takes dynamic loading issues into consideration.

Comment: My guess is also that it's related to dynamic libraries. While the standard doesn't officially support dynamic libraries, it still doesn't want to prevent those already hanging around as extensions.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons may be the following:

```
static char data[1000000000000000000000000000000];

void main(int argc)
{
    if (argc > 0)
        data[0] = 0;
}
```

It might be reasonable to allocate and init this static array only when it turns out that it is really needed. It might happen that some application were coming across something similar and had enough voice to convince the committee. In my own experience with C# I came across situation when static members of the class were not allocated right after jitting the class. They were allocated one by one, on the first use. In that case there was absolutely no justification for doing that. It was a plain disaster. Maybe they fixed this now.

Other reasons are possible also.

Comment: If the compiler can prove that you can't tell if it actually allocated that memory, then it doesn't have to actually allocate the memory, regardless of what the standard says. There is a clause called the "as-if rule" that guarantees this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306587/as-if-in-language-standards

Comment: The above code snippet is not an example of C++ dynamic initialization of static variables.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++11 draft:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the **first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit** as the variable to be initialized. *[emphasis mine]*

That is, the static variable has to be initialized before any use of anything defined in the same translation unit.

It looks to me that it is done this way to allow dynamic libraries (DLLs or SOs) to be loaded and initialized lazily, or even dynamically (calling `dlopen` or `LoadLibrary` or whatever).
It is obvious that a variable defined in a DLL cannot be initialized before the DLL itself is loaded.

Naturally, C++ knows nothing about DLLs so there is no direct mention to them in the standard. But the people from the commitee do know about real environments and compilers, and certainly know about DLLs. Without this clause, lazy loading a DLL would technically violate the C++ specification. (Not that it would prevent implementators to do it anyway, but it is better if we all try to go along with each other.)

And about which systems support this, that I know of, at least the MS Visual C++ compiler supports lazy dynamic linking (the DLL will not even be loaded until first use). And most modern platforms support dynamic loading a DLL.

Comment: In the case of dynamic loading/linking, the loader can perform dynamic initialization as part of the loading phase.  There is no need to inject code into the functions of a translation unit (TU) to ensure the TU's static data has been initialized before the functions operate on the data.  I'm wondering if this part of the standard is intended to allow for such code injection.

Comment: Yes, the loader can do that, and it can load a DLL _after_ `main` has already started. The standard does not impose the exact time of the initialization, so it is left to the convenience of the implementation. The limit is imposed in the _translation unit_ because that is the only linking block defined in the standard.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  So the crux of my question is, given that this part of the spec can be applied to this circumstance where loading occurs post-main, is that why it was written that way?  An alternative is this:  dynamic linking aside, a compiler vendor could postpone dynamic initialization as described, and instead inject code into each function that accesses the non-local variables, so they are initialized before use.  It would operate the same way as initialization of static local variables, except these are non-locals so the initialization code would have to be added to more than one function.

Comment: If a compiler did this, I think it would effectively solve the so-called "initialization order fiasco" problem.  I'm doubtful that any compiler does this, but a colleague of mine insists that some do.

Comment: The fact the language allows it doesn't mean that it is a good idea for the compiler. Yes, it might solve the _fiasco_, but it would incur in some overhead. And if you are willing to do it, you can write a function that returns a reference to a local static variable. About whether there are compilers that do that by default, I'm not totally sure, but I really don't think so.