# About c++ static init code limitation

Tags: c++

i am working with visual studio 2010. i use following code in some cpp files to run a function hundred times before the main function execute.

```
const int x = some_init_function()
```

but I found with visual studio, not every global x in init.
i want to ask if vc has limitation on this construct?

note:
in some_init_function is some code doing things such as registering. And the variable name is different in every cpp file.

Comment: Is the `x` in the same file as `main`?

Comment: Can you try rephrasing? "but I found with visual studio, not every global x in init." is gibberish to me; not at all sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you calling the function a hundred times before main? How do you know `x` is not initialized?

Comment: Simply cannot understand your question... Please try to rephrase it...

Comment: @KerrekSB no, in seperate compile units

Comment: I wonder how can you call a function before main() function?

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny If you use it to initialize a global constant, it could be called before main.

Comment: @NeilKirk That make sense, thanks.

Comment: @NeilKirk because i have breakpoints in some_init_function,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee that the code will run before `main()`, you need to make your variable `static` and put it in the same file as `main()`.  Otherwise it may not be initialized before `main()`.  For more on that, see here: [Is the static initialization of global variables completed before `main()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007701/is-the-static-initialization-of-global-variables-completed-before-main)

Alternatively, you can set up a "call before main" function in MSVC using a technique described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390626/4323

If you were using GCC, this would be done using `__attribute__((__constructor__))`.

Comment: thank you. i tried static before but does not work. it it difficult to let all the code in the same file as main() :(

Comment: You don't have to put the *code* into the same file as main(), only the *call*.  As in, you say `static const int x = foo();` in the same file as main, but you define `foo()` in another file.

Comment: to me this is the same :(

Comment: @rechardchen: OK then do what is shown in the link I gave you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113409/attribute-constructor-equivalent-in-vc/2390626#2390626 - namely `__declspec(allocate(".CRT$XCU"))`.  You can try this in the separate file and see if it works.